# How to Programmatically Close a Modal with Materialize.css

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, materialize

I am using `materialize.css` and have been trying to programmatically close a modal and then immediately open another.

This is the code I am currently using to `open/close`:

```
$('.modal').modal('close', "#modal1");
$('.modal').modal('open', "#modal2");
```

What actually happens is that when I call these functions, `#modal1` closes successfully, but its backdrop remains there as it is.

At exactly the same time, `#modal2` opens up and then *immediately* (in about 200 ms or so) closes back. Again, the backdrop stays unchanged.

Can I please get help to solve this?

The documentation calls `jQuery` *old*. So, am I using some depreacated method, and should I use a vanilla JavaScript equivalent for the same? What, if yes?

Comment: faced with the same issue? Any luck yet with this issue?

Comment: @JensO.AndersOlsén I had actually solved the problem. But, what version of Materialize are you using?

Answer (score 2):

For Materialize.js version v0.100 and above.

You can call a onClick function() to close/open multiple modals like below:

```
    <a href="#!" class="waves-effect waves-light btn" onclick="OpenCloseModal()">Button</a>
```

In below script when OpenCloseModal() function is executed here, it first closes the Modal (#modal1) and then opens the Modal (#modal2)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function closeOpenModal() {
       $('#modal1').modal('close');
       $('#modal2').modal('open');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

`$('#modal1').modal('close');`

`$('#modal2').modal('open');`

Comment: Although I finally realized that I was using `100.0.2-alpha` and was referring to the `1.0.0` docs, and already used what you suggested, the problem was, after all, not this!

Comment: $("#modal_id").modal('open', {
      dismissible: true,
      complete: function() { console.log('Close modal'); }
   })    for close and open put dismissible en false, that for materialize

Answer (score 0):

```
function close_modal() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("element-id");
    var instance = M.Modal.getInstance(elem);
    instance.close();
}
```

Comment: $("#modal_id").modal('open', {
      dismissible: true,
      complete: function() { console.log('Close modal'); }
   })    for close and open put dismissible en false, that for materialize

Answer (score 0):

No-JQuery way. First you should get an instance of modal that you intend to close. If e.g. on init you write:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".modal"); 
M.Modal.init(elems);
```

so in `elems` we have *NodeList* of all modals, for example we have three modals, to close second one you can say:

```
elems[1].M_Modal.close();
```

to open third:

```
elems[2].M_Modal.open();
```